# Not authorized to perform: sts:TagSession on resource: ***

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions

I'm trying to run a GitHub action to do a DB migration on AWS on staging server.

```
name: db migration for stg.

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging
    paths:
      - api/db/migrate/**

jobs:
  migration:
    name: DB Migration
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Configure AWS credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
      aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ASSUME_ROLE_ARN_STG }}
      role-duration-seconds: 1200
      aws-region: ap-northeast-1
     - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
     with:
      ruby-version: '2.7.2'
     - name: ssh configure
       env:
         SSH_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_SECRET_KEY }}
       run: |
         mkdir -p ~/.ssh && touch ~/.ssh/config
         echo 'host i-* mi-*' >> ~/.ssh/config
         echo '  ProxyCommand sh -c "aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p'"' >> ~/.ssh/config
         echo $SSH_SECRET_KEY | base64 -d > ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
         chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
      - name: db migration
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: <env>
          RAILS_MASTER_KEY: <key>
          RDS_HOSTNAME: 127.0.0.1
          RDS_DB_NAME: <db_name>
          RDS_USERNAME: <username>
          RDS_PASSWORD: <password>
          RDS_PORT: 9999
          STEP_SERVER_ID: <id>
          DB_HOST: <host>
          working-directory: ./api
          run: |
            ssh -f -N -L $RDS_PORT:$DB_HOST:3306 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa2 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ssm-user@$STEP_SERVER_ID
            sudo apt-get -yqq install libpq-dev
            gem install bundler
            bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3
            bundle exec rails db:migrate
```

What might be the reason im getting this error when running this action? Tried many number of steps to narrow down the reason for the issue, whether its causing by the `assumable_role` or secret value errors or trust relationships etc.. Can suggest what might be causing this?

```
Run aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
 with:
  aws-access-key-id: ***
  aws-secret-access-key: ***
  role-to-assume: ***
  role-duration-seconds: 1200
  aws-region: ap-northeast-1

Error: User: arn:aws:iam::***:user/github_user is not authorized to perform: sts:TagSession on resource: ***
```

Policy summary of the `github_user`

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
     {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:*",
        "Resource": "*"
     }
   ] 
}
```

Answer (score 40):

I figured this out.
The answer is there very subtly in the documentation, but you have to give the user the permission for sts:TagSession and then add that same permission to the permissions policy of the role that you are assuming.

**IAM User Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole",
                "sts:TagSession"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::11111111111:role/RoleToAssume",
   
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Trust Relationship on role that is being assumed**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::00000000000:user/UserFromAbove"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sts:AssumeRole",
        "sts:TagSession"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you run into: 
The requested DurationSeconds exceeds the MaxSessionDuration set for this role.

make sure you also add:
role-duration-seconds: 1200

Comment: For me this was kind of the issue, somehow the IAM user in the trust relationship policy was the user's access key. Replacing that with the user's ARN resolved the issue.

Comment: Do you mean "and then add that same permission to the **trust** policy of the role that you are assuming." ?

Comment: I could fix the issue without the policy. Setting `sts:AssumeRole` and `sts:TagSession` in the Trust Relationship was enough

Answer (score 4):

I had the following use case.

- An IAM User trying to assume a role using external ID using the following GHA

```
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
          role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE_TO_ASSUME }}
          role-external-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE_EXTERNAL_ID }}
          role-duration-seconds: 1200
          role-session-name: GithubBuildAndPushImageToECR
          role-skip-session-tagging: true
```

All I had to do was add `role-skip-session-tagging: true`

The above answers will work only if you are assuming a role through OIDC WedIdentiyy
https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials#session-tagging-and-name

Hope this saves someones day , I wasn't that lucky :-P

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Chris which helped obviously to solve this issue:

- When you have created the role using `OIDC`. It has a `trust relationship`. This means some `Github Actions` would have to be added to it as `principle` and it will assume that role and whatever permission this role has will be applied to federated OIDC identity `Federated": "arn:aws:iam::636521895949:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"` in this case - Github Actions.
- In addition, The User has to be there to provide short-lived tokens using `AWS STS`, so GitHub actions can assume that role. So, `Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::636527382793:user/<UserName>"` should have `"Action": "sts:AssumeRole"`.
- This means the **Trust relationship on role** can look like this as putting actions in a list is not allowed `Action": ["sts:AssumeRole", "sts:TagSession"]`:
  Lets call this role `s3RoleForGitHubActions`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::6363891738271:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "StringLike": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:github.com/GitHubProfile/GithubRepo/*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::6365738978321:user/UserName"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::6365738978321:user/UserName"
            },
            "Action": "sts:TagSession"
        }
    ]
}
```

Finally, We need to provide the `IAM User` a policy that will allow itself to assume that role we created, so **The IAM user policy**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole",
                "sts:TagSession"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::63738127982:role/s3RoleForGitHubActions"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using CDK and maintaining the user yourself (rotating credentials etc), then following snippet can be used to create user and role with session tags on the trusted entity:

```js
import * as iam from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';

// The user that will be creating credentials
const someUser = new iam.User(this, 'SomeUser');

// Role that will be assumed by the user
const someRole = new iam.Role(this, 'SomeRole', {
    assumedBy: new iam.ArnPrincipal(someUser.userArn).withSessionTags(),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I solved it, by adding permissions to my gh-action pipeline to read the id-token of Github itself, that's what makes the oidc work in my case.

For the case shared by @Ragnar921

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging
    paths:
      - api/db/migrate/**

jobs:
  migration:
    name: DB Migration
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

### add it ########
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
###################
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Configure AWS credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
      aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ASSUME_ROLE_ARN_STG }}
      role-duration-seconds: 1200
      aws-region: ap-northeast-1
     - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
     with:
      ruby-version: '2.7.2'
     - name: ssh configure
       env:
         SSH_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_SECRET_KEY }}
       run: |
         mkdir -p ~/.ssh && touch ~/.ssh/config
         echo 'host i-* mi-*' >> ~/.ssh/config
         echo '  ProxyCommand sh -c "aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p'"' >> ~/.ssh/config
         echo $SSH_SECRET_KEY | base64 -d > ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
         chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
      - name: db migration
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: <env>
          RAILS_MASTER_KEY: <key>
          RDS_HOSTNAME: 127.0.0.1
          RDS_DB_NAME: <db_name>
          RDS_USERNAME: <username>
          RDS_PASSWORD: <password>
          RDS_PORT: 9999
          STEP_SERVER_ID: <id>
          DB_HOST: <host>
          working-directory: ./api
          run: |
            ssh -f -N -L $RDS_PORT:$DB_HOST:3306 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa2 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ssm-user@$STEP_SERVER_ID
            sudo apt-get -yqq install libpq-dev
            gem install bundler
            bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3
            bundle exec rails db:migrate
```

It is not required to add any additional trusted relationship on the role that is been assumed by the gh-runner itself, only what is required by the OIDC, like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "StringLike": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": [
                        "repo:XXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYY:pull_request",
                        "repo:XXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYY:ref:refs/heads/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```